# Autocmd for scrolling a window?

Tags: autocmd

Is there a autocmd for scrolling a window without moving a cursor, the one that occurs for CTRL+E/Y? Is there some autocmd that is triggered for that?  I googled but found nothing.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/138251).  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @jamessan I'm trying to resolve https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/776 (I'm reporter of that issue). I got to `matchparen.vim` using `CursorMoved`, `CursorMovedI`, `WinEnter`, `TextChanged` and `TextChangedI` for doing it's job. A simple fix would be adding something like `WindowScrolled` there. But it seems that it doesn't exist. But ofc it's possible that this is XY problem. Any idea how to do this in some different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at [`:h autocommand-events`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-events) you will see all events triggered.

There is no autocommand that I see for scrolling without cursor moving.

If you want to add extra functionalities to `<C-e>`/`<C-y>` you can always remap them:

```
nnoremap <C-E> :echo 'a'<CR> | norm <C-E>
```